# как отрефакторить алгоритм с массивами?

Tags: javascript

Задача такая. Есть массив, который состоит из 20 объектов с пустыми данными (в интерфейсе это 20 пустых карточек). Извне приходит другой массив при обновлении страницы. Нужно произвести вставку элементов из пришедшего массива  в созданный пустой. 
Например Если приходит 5 элементов, то отображаем 5 пришедших элементов и 15 оставшихся пустых.

Если приходит 7 элементов, то отображаем сначала 7 элементов пришедших, а потом 13 пустых.

Если пришло 21 элемент, то отображаем 21 пришедший элемент.

Я написал алгоритм, но помогите его отрефакторить. И разделить по методам, чтобы это смотрелось достойно.

```
const updateArray = EntryArray => {
  let cardsFake = new Array(20).fill({
    url: '',
    title: '',
    id: '',
    name: '',
  });
  EntryArray = EntryArray.reverse();
  EntryArray.forEach(item => {
     cardsFake.unshit(item);
    if (EntryArray.length <= 20) {
      cardsFake = cardsFake.slice(0, 20);
    } else {
      cardsFake = cardsFake.slice(0, EntryArray.length);
    }
  });

  return cardsFake;
};
```

Comment: `item.unshift(item);` - ??

Comment: ошибся cardsFake.unshit(item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подход в задаче выбран неправильный.

Вместо создания заранее массива пустых, и добавления в него, намного проще проверить длину переданного массива и если она меньше нужной добавить нужное количество пустых.

Например:

```
function updateArray(arr, minLength = 20){
    if(arr.length < minLength){
        arr.push(...new Array(minLength-arr.length).fill({
            url: '',
            title: '',
            id: '',
            name: '',
        })); // если нужно менять переданный массив

        /* return arr.concat(new Array(minLength-arr.length).fill({
            url: '',
            title: '',
            id: '',
            name: '',
        })); // если не нужно менять переданный массив */
    }
    return arr; // либо `arr.slice()` если нужна именно копия массива
}
```

---

Примеры с изменением исходного массива и без.

```js
function updateArray(arr, minLength = 20) {
  if (arr.length < minLength) {
    arr.push(...new Array(minLength - arr.length).fill({
      url: '',
      title: '',
      id: '',
      name: '',
    })); // если нужно менять переданный массив
  }
  return arr; // либо `arr.slice()` если нужна именно копия массива
}

function getNewArray(arr, minLength = 20) {
  if (arr.length < minLength) {
    return arr.concat(new Array(minLength - arr.length).fill({
      url: '',
      title: '',
      id: '',
      name: '',
    })); // если не нужно менять переданный массив
  }
  return arr.slice(); // если нужна именно копия массива
}


var a = [1, 2, 3];
updateArray(a, 5);
console.log('a', a);

var b = [1, 2];
var c = getNewArray(b, 5);
console.log('b', b);
console.log('c', c);
```